# Google Cloud: Why am I not an organization administrator?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to expand my usage of Google Cloud and running into issues.  When I go to IAM & Admin -> IAM and select my organization, I get an error:  "You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page".  A bit lower:  "You are missing the following required permissions:  resourcemanager.organizations.getIamPolicy".

I'm confused by this because if I select a project IN the organization I see I have the "Organization Administrator" role which has that exact permission assigned.  I also have "Owner" role.

I also cannot upgrade from Basic support to any paid support due to this issue, so I literally cannot get any help from anyone at Google.

I created this org!  Do I need to delete everything and start over?  (ugh)

Comment: Organization Admin must be applied (bound) at the organization level. If you created the organization, then you have a Workspace or Identity account. Use that account to login. Otherwise, edit your question with more details. The problem should be easy to solve once you are using the correct account to authenticate.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am logged in on the account that created the organization.  There is no other account.  I'm the only one that has every done anything with it.  Can you explain what other details I can provide?

Comment: For example, are you using Google Workspace or Identity Platform?

Comment: Google search for "Google Workspace: Turn Google Cloud Platform on or off for users".

Comment: It's definitely not Identity Platform, must be Google Workspace.  Of which I am not the administrator.  So I'm guessing that when I logged into Cloud console and created an organization, it automatically made the org admin the user that created the workspace?

Comment: The Workspace Admin must enable Google Cloud and setup IAM bindings for you. Read the document in my previous comment.

Comment: based on what you said in the comments above _I am logged in on the account that created the organization_ if that is the case, your organization is managing your Google Workspace's account. Unless you request your Workspace Admin to [configure your account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6167160?hl=en), as @JohnHanley suggested.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what @JohnHanley's shared on the comments:

> Organization Admin must be applied (bound) at the organization level. If you created the organization, then you have a Workspace or Identity account. Use that account to login. The problem should be easy to solve once you are using the correct account to authenticate.

In addittion to that;

To administer a particular project or product on GCP, you must ask your organization or the team managing your Google Workspace Admin to [increase your role and authorization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6167160?hl=en) to a higher hierarchy.